# How to randomize data in unity using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, unityscript

I have a text file in project with some text data. Using below code I'm showing my data one line at a time when player click on a button (called NEXT).

For some reason what I want to do is make a button called "RANDOM". And when player will click on that a random line from the text file will be shown.
Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
  #pragma strict

  import UnityEngine;
  import UnityEngine.UI;

  var textFile : TextAsset;
  var dialogLines : String [];
  var lineNumber : int;

  var uiText : Text;
  var canvas : Canvas;


  function Start () {
    if (textFile){
        dialogLines = (textFile.text.Split("\n"[0]));
  }


  }

  function Update () {
    if(lineNumber <0){
    lineNumber = 0;
    }

    var dialog : String = dialogLines[lineNumber];
    uiText.text = dialog;
  }

  function Next () {
    var randomLine = Math.floor((Math.random() * dialogLines.length) + 1); //1-10
    //if dialogLines is not strictly typed, go ahead and use dialogLines.length instead of 10
    return dialogLines[randomLine];
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function like so

```
function randomLine() {
  var randomLine = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); //1-10
  //if dialogLines is not strictly typed, go ahead and use dialogLines.length instead of 10
  return dialogLines[randomLine];
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I will let you know the result soon :)

Comment: It is saying [Unknown identifier: "Math"]

Comment: nice, is everything working as intended or do you have any additional questions?

Comment: [ERROR] It is saying [Unknown identifier: "Math"]

Comment: That's bizarre, Math is just like a default library. I just checked unityscript stuff and found you have to use this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html instead of `Math.random`, that's kinda dumb but whatever

Comment: Still I did not got what I have to use. Can you help me with that please

Comment: Or can you give me a c# script for this purpose?

Comment: To get a random number in c# `Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);` this will return a number 0 - 100

Comment: Did `Random.value` not work though, could you explain the error? This unity script says it should be working fine https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your file split into an array just do grab a random line number.

```
Math.rndRange = function ( min, max ){
    if( isNaN(min) || isNaN(max) ) return NaN;
    return Math.round(Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
}
```

Maybe do a floor or something instead of round. W.e you want.